# Alter edit link behaviour in a view

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to change the URL of the node edit link for a specific view.
This is what I have done and it (almost) works:

1. created a file **mymodule/views/mymodule.views.inc** with the following code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function kd_ari_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'mymodule', 'views/views_handler_field_article_link_edit');
  $data['views_entity_node']['edit_node']['field']['handler'] = 'views_handler_field_article_link_edit';
}
```

2. created a second file **mymodule/views/views_handler_field_article_link_edit.inc** with the following code:

```
class views_handler_field_article_link_edit extends views_handler_field_node_link {

 function render_link($node, $values) {
   if (!node_access('update', $node)) {
     return;
   }
   $this->options['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
   $this->options['alter']['path'] = 'admin/mymodule/' . $node->nid;
   $text = !empty($this->options['text']) ? $this->options['text'] : t('edit');
   return $text;
 }
}
```

The problem is that the view displays the edit link only one time after I clear all caches... afterwards the display link is gone. Any tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you tell me exactly what do you want to do ? just want to  have a column with edit label and link to `admin/mymodule/[nid]` path?

Comment: @zhilevan yes that is exactly what I want to achieve

Comment: Ok, but you choose hard solution, views is powerful, try easier methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Nid as field,
Set Label to Operation (or anything you want ), 
 in *Rewrite results* section

- check **Override the output of this field with custom text**  and
  enter *Edit* text.
- check **Output this field as a custom link** and in the input box
  enter  `admin/mymodule/[nid]` .

save the field and enjoy the power of views rewriting.

[image]